# How to smoothly change the radius of a circle by dragging its circumference?

Tags: graphics

I am attempting to set an `EventHandler` to change the radius of a circle by dragging on its circumference. But the response to the dragging is terribly slow. What is wrong with the code?

```
cnt[p_] := Return[Round /@ p];
grids[min_, max_] := 
  Join[Range[Ceiling[min], Floor[max]], 
   Table[{j + 1, Lighter@Lighter@Lighter@Lighter@Blue}, {j, 
     Round[min], Round[max - 1], 1}]];

DynamicModule[{pnt = {1, 1}, VPOS = {1, 1}, rad = 1},
  Dynamic@Graphics[
   {Thick,
    EventHandler[
     Circle[ cnt[pnt] , rad],
     {
      "MouseDragged" :> (
        VPOS = MousePosition["Graphics"];
          rad = EuclideanDistance[pnt, VPOS];
        )
      },
     PassEventsDown -> True
     ],
    Locator[Dynamic[pnt], None] 
    },
   Axes -> True,
   GridLines -> grids,
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}] 
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Is `EventHandler` a need? Using `Locator` might be easier.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to test how to correctly set an `EventHandler`.

Comment: It's probably slow because of the `EuclideanDistance`.

Comment: Is it again the problem of out of focus? Seems it only response when the mouse is right on the top of the circumference. Is there a way of work-around?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  I can move the circle when I click the mouse on its center, and when I mouseclick on the circumference, the size changes.  Are you interested in being able to **both** move the circle and change its size with the mouse?

Comment: @bobthechemist I think the problem is that the circle doesn't move when you move your mouth, it just moves a few milliseconds after.

Comment: @bobthechemist Yes, exactly. It is no problem to move the circle, but it is hardly to change its size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The front end's event handling mechanism seems to have a hard time deciding which event should be passed to the locator. Therefore, I think it's best to dispense with the locator. This seems to work fairly well:

```
cnt[p_] := Return[Round /@ p];

grids[min_, max_] :=
  Join[
    Range[Ceiling[min], Floor[max]], 
    Table[{j + 1, Lighter @ Lighter @ Lighter @ Lighter @ Blue}, 
      {j, Round[min], Round[max - 1], 1}]];

DynamicModule[{pnt = {1, 1}, VPOS = {1, 1}, rad = 1, d},
 EventHandler[
   Dynamic @ 
     Graphics[{{PointSize[Medium], Point[cnt[pnt]]}, {Thick, Circle[cnt[pnt], rad]}},
       Axes -> True,
       GridLines -> grids,
      PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}],
  {"MouseDragged" :> (
     VPOS = MousePosition["Graphics"];
     d = EuclideanDistance[pnt, VPOS]; 
     If[d < 1, pnt = VPOS, rad = d])}]]
```

[image: graphics]

I made the center point visible as an aid to dragging the circle from grid point to grid point. I also need to point out that, when adjusting the radius, it is best to drag from just outside the circle.

Comment: It's much better than the OP's answer indeed, but moving the centre too fast catches the circle sometimes..

Comment: @Öskå. Yeah, that's why I wrote "This seems to work fairly well" rather than "This seems to work well". It does meet the requirement of moving the circumference smoothly.