# How to manipulate a circle in GeoGebra style?

Tags: graphics, front-end, dynamic, geometry, gui-construction

I want to emulate the [GeoGebra app](http://web.geogebra.org/chromeapp/). I want to get an effect like this in *Mathematica*.

[image]

I don't know how to move whole circle without changing the radius of the circle.

My sample code：

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{Circle[p, Norm[p2 - p]]}, PlotRange -> 5, Frame -> 1], 
  {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}, 
  {{p2, {2, 2}}, Locator}]
```

Comment: Related, though almost the converse of this question: [(56390)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56390)

Comment: Closely related [30354](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30354/5478)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I find more intuitive:

```
circle[] := DynamicModule[{a = {0, 0}, b = {1, 0}, r = 1, w},
  {
   Dynamic@Circle[a, r],
   Locator[Dynamic[a, {(w = b - a) &, (a = #; b = a + w) &, None}]],
   Locator[Dynamic[b, (b = #; r = Norm[b - a]) &]]

   }]

Graphics[circle[], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 2]
```

[image]

---

And this is what fits well OP's example:

```
circle2[] := DynamicModule[{a = {0, 0}, b = {1, 0}, r = 1, s, p, hand},
  {Thick,
   EventHandler[
    Dynamic@hand@Circle[a, r],
    {"MouseDown" :> {s = {p[], a, b}; },
     "MouseDragged" :> {{a, b} = (p[] - s[[1]] + #) & /@ Rest[s]}

     }],
   Locator[Dynamic[a, (a = #; r = Norm[b - a]) &]], 
   Locator[Dynamic[b, (b = #; r = Norm[b - a]) &]]}

  ,
  Initialization :> (
    p[] := MousePosition["Graphics"];
    hand = MouseAppearance[#, "LinkHand"] &;
    )]

Graphics[circle2[], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 2]
```

You can improve styling ofc.

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't have the behavior the OP asks for.

Comment: Still seems wrong. Dragging the center locator doesn't change the radius. Dragging on the circle's circumference doesn't move it.

Comment: I have now. It meets the specs. I like it. But I don't like `circle`. I think it detracts from your answer to leave it in.

Comment: @m_goldberg Ok, removed :)

Comment: Personally, I preferred the original `circle` based version - which garnered my upvote. While it didn't replicate the GeoGebra behavior exactly, it certainly got the same idea across and with much simpler code. Furthermore, it's not clear from the question that an exact replication was necessary - at least not to me.

Answer (score 10):

I do nor know how to implement what you want to do in a `Manipulate` expression using locators, because I don't know how to handle mouse events in a `Manipulate` expression. However, if you are willing to accept an answer using `EventHandler`, the behavior you ask for isn't very difficult to implement.

```
With[{δ = .2}, 
  DynamicModule[{p1 = {0, 0}, p2 = {2, 2}, mouse, action, dp},
    EventHandler[
      Dynamic @ Graphics[{
          {PointSize[Large], Point[{p1, p2}]},
          {Thick, Circle[p1, Norm[p2 - p1]]}},
        Frame -> True,
        PlotRange -> 5],
      {"MouseDown" :>
        (mouse = MousePosition["Graphics"];
         action =
          Which[
           Norm[p1 - mouse] < δ , "p1",
           Norm[p2 - mouse] < δ , "p2",
           Abs[Norm[mouse - p1] - Norm[p2 - p1]] < δ , "circle"]),
       "MouseDragged" :>
        (mouse = MousePosition["Graphics"];
         Switch[action,
          "p1", p1 = mouse,
          "p2", p2 = mouse,
          "circle", dp = p2 - p1; p1 = mouse; p2 = p1 + dp])}]]]
```

[image: dynamic-circle]

The plan behind this code is

- A mouse-down event detects what visual object the mouse is near. This in turn sets what action should be done during the drag.
- A mouse-dragged event carries out the selected action.

Comment: I like that Mouse-Action stuff! Cool.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {3, 3};
y = {5, 3};
LocatorPane[Dynamic[{x, y}], 
 Dynamic@Graphics[{{Gray, Circle[x, Abs[y[[1]] - x[[1]]]]}, {Blue, 
     PointSize[0.02], Point[{x, {y[[1]], x[[2]]}}]}}, Axes -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 8}, {-2, 8}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
 Appearance -> None]
```