# Create a Manipulate with a control to select Circle or Disk

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

I need to create a `Manipulate` that shows a circle or disk with a control to select whether it is `Circle` or `Disk` and sliders to set the `{x,y}` coordinates, radius and color (`Hue`).

My code is

```
type={"Disk","Circle"};

Manipulate[ip = Position[type,choose];
  If[ip == {{2}}, Show[Graphics[{Hue[a], Circle[{x, y}, r]}], 
    Axes->True, PlotRange -> {{-5,5}, {-5,5}}],
  If[ip == {{1}}, Show[Graphics[{Hue[a], Disk[{x, y}, r]}], 
    Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], Print["No Plot"]]], 
 {choose, type, ControlType -> PopupMenu}, 
 {a, -1, 1}, {x, -4, 5}, {y, -4, 5}, {r, 1, 5}]
```

However, on selecting circle it keeps on loading again and again.
I am not able to find the error. What is wrong with this code.

Comment: related: [How to manipulate a circle in GeoGebra style?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A streamlined version of your code:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Hue[a], choose[{x, y}, r]}, Axes -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], 
 {choose, {Disk, Circle}, ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 {a, -1, 1}, {x, -4, 5}, {y, -4, 5}, {r, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell where I am going wrong in my code? why it is executing again and again?

Comment: @SurbhiGrover, your code works fine in version 9 (windows 10) and version 11.3 (wolfram cloud).